# A more functionrich number (than Bigdecimal) holding java library

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

- The operation should try and keep the answer of the same type as the original inputs, thus if the holder started of with a Double then the result should also be a double.
- If inputs contain holders of different number types then it should auto widden etc.
- There should be a single type of Holder with getters to return the result as an integer, double, bigdecimal, big integer etc with exceptions thrown if conversion fails.
- Code should look like Bigdecimal.
- Ideally immutable
- Code shouldnt know or care whats inside the holder, operations just work until conversion is needed at a later stage.
- Unfortunately BigDecimal is not really complete for my needs its missing many key functions eg: sine, log and most of the static helpers on Math.

*ApacheCommonsMath*

Axelcb made a suggestion to use the apache commons math library. The main class of use in my case seem to be DFP.

- Examining DFP there is no simple way to pass a BigDecimal/BigInteger and build a DFP. It would be nice if precision would also be a parameter and used during the suck in process.
- none of the functions (like multiply) accept a context w/ a precision and rounding just like BigDecimal. I really dont understand the reasoning for the clunky way precisions and rounding are handled.
- What is a DfpField, what exactly does it do and why are there fields in a DFP ??? Please dont tell me this Calendar again.
- there are no methods to export to a BigDecimal or BigInteger

*dfp*

- is this the original inspiration for apache commons math DFP class ?
- the first concern about import from a BigDecimal or BigInteger is lacking.
- there are no methods to export to a BigDecimal or BigInteger

Comment: That sound like a wish where's the question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the package [gnu.math](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/api/gnu/math/package-summary.html) from the [kawa language framework](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/index.html) which is used to implement the full Scheme "numeric tower". The package should be pretty self-contained and independent from the rest of kawa.

Comment: Licensed as MIT :) It seems to contain many of the "extra" functionality i was after so i will accept it anyway and contionue to study it.

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal` is not `final`. You can extend it and add the methods (sine, log, etc) to the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I know these libraries which may be usable for you:

- [High Performance Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic Package](http://apfloat.org)
- [Decimal Floating Point Java class library](http://dfp.sourceforge.net/) which is now part of the [Commons-Math 2.2 API](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/dfp/package-summary.html)
- [JScience Real Implementation](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Real.html)

Comment: Commons-math DFP is floating point not exact like BigDecimal. It is also missing many common functions like the trig stuff - its not that much of improvement over BigDecimal in terms of converging towards the stuff in java.math.Math.

Comment: In the DfpMath class of the org.apache.commons.math.dfp package you can find the trig stuff.

Comment: As the Javadoc of the Dfp class said: "Another floating point class. This one is built using radix 10000 which is 10^4, so its *almost decimal* (not exact Decimal math, but close to it)".

Comment: Half the problem is while DFP is more feature complete its almost like they completely forgot about enriching its non floating point equivalent :( - im talking about a better Bigdecimal where :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to write wrapper for BigDecimal and implement all your additional options.

Comment: But thats the point i dont want to implement 30-40 functions that are on java.lang.Math and missing on BigDecimal.